# Howto use C++ do pipe run python and capture stdout/stderr output?

Tags: c++, process, pipe

We know that python supports running some short statements with the `-c` command line without creating a .py script file.
In addition, python can also be started through the command line pipeline, reading the script stream from the upstream of its pipeline and executing it. From the Windows command line it looks like this:

```
C:\> echo print('hello') | python.exe
hello
```

This way there is also no need to create a .py script file.
I would like to know how to complete the above command line function through C++ code, pipeline input is

```
std::string pyscript = R"(print('hello'))";
```

Send it to the sub-process python.exe, and then get the standard output and error output strings of the sub-process python.exe to

```
std::string pyout;
std::string pyerr;
```

At least it needs to be a method that can be used under Windows. It would be better if it can be cross-platform.

To abstract this problem a little more, it is actually how to use C++ to implement the pipeline execution of the operating system command line and obtain the final output content. I don't want to need to create temporary files during this process.

```
C:\> echo print('hello') | any_program.exe
```

I tried code like this, but not get what I need:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/process/windows.hpp>

int Run(
    const std::string& exeName,         ///< could also be UTF-16 for Windows
    const std::string& args,            ///< could also be UTF-16 for Windows
    const std::string& input,           ///< [in] data for stdin
    std::string& output,                ///< [out] data from stdout
    std::string& error                  ///< [out] data from stderr
)
{
    using namespace boost;

    asio::io_service ios;

    // stdout setup
    //
    std::vector<char> vOut(128 << 10);           // that worked well for my decoding app.
    auto outBuffer{ asio::buffer(vOut) };
    process::async_pipe pipeOut(ios);

    std::function<void(const system::error_code & ec, std::size_t n)> onStdOut;
    onStdOut = [&](const system::error_code & ec, size_t n)
    {
        output.reserve(output.size() + n);
        output.insert(output.end(), vOut.begin(), vOut.begin() + n);
        if (!ec)
        {
            asio::async_read(pipeOut, outBuffer, onStdOut);
        }
    };

    // stderr setup
    //
    std::vector<char> vErr(128 << 10);
    auto errBuffer{ asio::buffer(vErr) };
    process::async_pipe pipeErr(ios);

    std::function<void(const system::error_code & ec, std::size_t n)> onStdErr;
    onStdErr = [&](const system::error_code & ec, size_t n)
    {
        error.reserve(error.size() + n);
        error.insert(error.end(), vErr.begin(), vErr.begin() + n);
        if (!ec)
        {
            asio::async_read(pipeErr, errBuffer, onStdErr);
        }
    };

    // stdin setup
    //
    auto inBuffer{ asio::buffer(input) };
    process::async_pipe pipeIn(ios);

    process::child c(
        exeName + " " + args,                   // exeName must be full path
        process::std_out > pipeOut, 
        process::std_err > pipeErr, 
        process::std_in < pipeIn
    );

    asio::async_write(pipeIn, inBuffer, 
        [&](const system::error_code & ec, std::size_t n) 
        {
            pipeIn.async_close();                     //  tells the child we have no more data
        });

    asio::async_read(pipeOut, outBuffer, onStdOut);
    asio::async_read(pipeErr, errBuffer, onStdErr);

    ios.run();
    c.wait();
    return c.exit_code();                            // return the process' exit code.
}


int main() {
    using namespace std;
    string pycmd = R"(
import re
print(re.match(r'.*', "sdafsdf"))
    )";
    string oo, ee;
    Run(
        R"(C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe)",
        "",
        pycmd,
        oo,
        ee
    );
    cout << oo << ee << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My expected output is

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='sdafsdf'>
```